# How to make link change colour when mouse hovers over it

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change the color of a link when a mouse hovers over the tags h2 and p.The problem is that when the mouse hovers over them I can only see a border under them. I have tried many things but still nothing to solve it. Here is the HTML code and CSS.

```
.info:hover{
   color:yellow;

 }

 h2{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
   color :#999;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   font-family:OpenSansI;
   font-size:25px;
}

p{
   color :#999;
   font-family:OpenSansI;

  }

<div class="row" >
        <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a class="info" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
            <h2>Who am I...</h2>
            <p>I am</p>

        </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a  class="info" href="#">
            <h2>My CV</h2>
            <p>CV</p>

        </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <a class="info" href="#">
            <h2>Contact with me</h2>
            <p>Mail</p>

        </a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you hover over the a tag that both the H2 and P tags change colors?

Answer (score 0):

because you have a another element within your link you have to reference that too.

```
.info h2:hover, p:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
```

example - https://jsfiddle.net/dL9uz1d3/1/

**UPDATED ANSWER**

updated example - https://jsfiddle.net/dL9uz1d3/11/
It wasnt clear that you wanted them to function as one. There are many tutorials on css out there. It would be no harm to check some of them out. Anyway here is an updated answer

```
<div class="row" >
    <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <a class="info" href="http://www.w3schools.com">
        <h2>Who am I...</h2>
        I am
    </a>
    </div>
</div>

a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color :#999;
   font-family:OpenSansI;
}
a.info:hover, h2:hover {
   color:yellow;
   text-decoration: none;
}
h2{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
   color :#999;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   font-family:OpenSansI;
   font-size:25px;
}
```

Links by default are underlined. To remove the underline on links you set `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: I want to change the color h2 and p.Your example change h2 or p.

Comment: Well you dont need paragraph tags within a link. so yeah if you want to have `<p>` tags put them in and change this - `a.info:hover, h2:hover {` to this - `a.info:hover, h2:hover, p:hover {`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what color `.info` is. All the text inside `.info` elements is contained in `h2` or `p` elements and they have their own colors set (so they are not `color: inherit`).

You'd need to target them explicitly:

```
.info {
    color: #999;
}

.info:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

.info h2,
.info p {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: The border not change and still i can see other border under of h2 and p when mouse hover it..

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy to do what you want and keep the same markup with the H2 and P tags in the A tags. by adding the `:hover` on the `.info` class instead you can insure to change anything inside on hover.

```
.info:hover h2, .info:hover p {
  color:yellow;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dmo1dff/1/)

Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes,that's it but when i hovered created a border under <a>...Why?

Comment: @user3906418 Check out the updated JSFIDDLE link above. that was just the text-decoration that was making the border.